# Unique Name for Navigation Item in Umbraco

Tags: xslt, menu, navigation, umbraco

I am using the default umbTopNavigation.xslt file and would like to have different navigation menu item names from the URLs. Currently, whatever I name the page in the Content Editor determines the URL of that page, (ie. About Us = about-us.aspx). But what if I want the menu item to read "About Us" but the URL be "about.aspx" ? I added a textstring to the doctype with the id "menuItemName" but I am not sure what the proper syntax is to edit this code to have that in it:

```
<ul id="topNavigation" class="nav">
 <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
  <li>
    <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">current</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <a class="navigation" href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
     <span><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></span>
    </a>
  </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Obviously this is the line that needs to be changed:

```
<span><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></span>
```

...but I don't know what to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I never understood what I was reading when I kept seeing articles about umbracoUrlName, but I finally figured it out.

Basically, I keep the code above the same, but I just changed the alias from menuItemName to umbracoUrlName (it is a textstring) and whatever I put in there is what the URL is for that page!

Geeze, I feel silly now, but at least it is working!

Comment: your solution works. to answer your question, however, `<xsl:value-of select="./menuItemName"/>` should do the trick, assuming you're using the new xml schema (umbraco 4.5+)